# Manipulating Salesforce html elements with Autohotkey via COM

Tags: html, automation

I wrote an Autohotkey script that uses COM to automate updating Salesforce opportunities. At some point, the functionality broke. Previously, I could use javascript alerts to determine which HTML elements I needed to manipulate, e.g, javascript: alert(document.forms[3].elements[8].value) would return "Save".
I would then click the Save button with Autohotkey by specifying that element.
Now I get error messages in Autohotkey and all alerts return "Unable to download . Unspecified error"

I have a very beginner level understanding of HTML, so I'm not sure what this means. Can anyone provide any guidance?

Comment: That's a pretty strange error and doesn't sound related to anything directly HTML / Salesforce lingo.  That said the javascript you posted is pretty specific and if Salesforce makes any changes it could easily break (i.e. it's elements[9] now).  You might consider also posting this to the [super user stack exchange](http://superuser.com) about the autohotkey issue.

Comment: Yeah, they did change the Save button Element number in the past, but I was able to figure it out with the alerts. Now, I've checked almost every element from 1 to 20 in forms 0-3 and they all give the same error. Could Salesforce have protected the elements in some way? 
I'll try posting this to the super user stack exchange. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Almost sounds like your JavaScript library didn't load.

Comment: @turbo There are some security measures around this sort of thing, but from your explanation I don't think they'd be an issue.  I hate to give a cop-out answer and I don't have much but a gut feeling to base this on, but it feels like this is going to be an issue with Autohotkey not Salesforce.

Comment: @turbotuli you also might consider looking into using the data loader or possibly workflow (or other options) to do your opportunity updates.